# dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js: Uncaught TypeError: a.settings()[0] is undefined

Tags: jquery, datatables

[image]
dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js: Uncaught TypeError: a.settings()[0] is undefined

using the theme https://eatio-bootstrap-admin-template.netlify.app

Comment: Can you please add your relevant code?

Comment: https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.9/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js or without min i.e https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.9/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.js